# grepl() and lapply to fill missing values

Tags: regex, r, data.table, lapply, grepl

I have the following data as an example:

```
fruit.region <- data.frame(full =c("US red apple","bombay Asia mango","gold kiwi New Zealand"), name = c("apple", "mango", "kiwi"), country = c("US","Asia","New Zealand"), type = c("red","bombay","gold"))
```

I would like R to be able to look at other items in the "full" (name) column that don't have values for "name", "country" and "type" and see if they match other items. For instance, if full had a 4th row with "bombay US mango" it would be able to identify that the country should read US, bombay should be under type and mango should be under name.

This is what I have so far, which merely identifies (logically) where the items match:

```
new.entry <- c("bombay US mango")
split.new.entry <- strsplit(new.entry, " ")

lapply(split.new.entry, function(x){
 check = grepl(x, fruit.region, ignore.case=TRUE)
 print(check)
})
```

I'm at a bit of a standstill..I've read through a number of regex posts and the r help guides on `grepl` but am not able to find a great solution. What I have  doesn't fully identify a logical "match" vector so I'm unable to subset and use an if statement to concatenate on different elements. Ideally, I'd like to be able to replace these elements in data.table form as my fruit.region will actually be in a data table. Does anyone have any suggestions on the best approach?

Comment: Please format your input data frame as a table, and then show us the exact output you want.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `str_detect` function from the stringr library. This gives a list, ready to `rbind`:

```
library(stringr)
addnewrow <- function(newfruit){
  z<-lapply(fruit.region[,2:4], function(x) x[str_detect(new.entry, x)])
  z$full <- newfruit
  z
}
addnewrow(new.entry)

$name
[1] "mango"

$country
[1] "US"

$type
[1] "bombay"

$full
[1] "bombay US mango"
```

The next step would depend on your desired outcome - if you only want to add one, try:

```
rbind(fruit.region, addnewrow(new.entry))
```

If you have a lot:

```
z <- do.call(rbind, lapply(c(new.entry, new.entry), addnewrow))
rbind(fruit.region, z)
```

NB make sure your columns are character first:

```
fruit.region[] <- lapply(fruit.region, as.character)
```

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy - that's helpful. One follow-up: I seem to have it figured out when adding on values when new.entry is one line item. When I try to add on something along the lines of: new.entry <- c("apple, Asia, gold","mango US bombay","kiwi, Asia, red") and then run that through: 

z <- do.call(rbind, lapply(new.entry, addnewrow))
rbind(fruit.region, z)

I end up getting output that doesn't properly place the new items into their proper categories. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?? Thanks

Comment: You should mark your accepted answers as correct and probably upvote them too. People like to be rewarded for their help.